# Fixed column width on Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a table that is empty until the user do some actions. The problem is that when the table is empty, the column have one width and when the table has content (some inputs on `td`) the width changes. What i want is to keep the column size fixed, that is, the same column size when the table is empty and when it has content.

The following code shows de Datatable configuration. That widths shown are what i need but, for example, when the table is empty, the first column has `width` of `114px`

```
tabla = $('#tabla').DataTable({
    language: {
        url: '/recursos/estilos/DataTables-1.10.1/js/locale/es_AR.json'
    },          
    "bSort": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
     aoColumns : [
      { "sWidth": "104px"},
      { "sWidth": "263px"},
      { "sWidth": "105px"},
      { "sWidth": "105px"},
      { "sWidth": "105px"},
      { "sWidth": "105px"},
      { "sWidth": "33px"},
    ]
});
```

Comment: Try putting `sScrollX: "100%",` as datatable paramter

Comment: assign any one columns width as auto.

Answer (score 2):

I **SOLVED THE PROBLEM** just adding divs on `th` width fixed widths.

In the table definition i had this `HTML` with the `Datatable` configuration shown on the question:

```
<thead>
    <tr>                            
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>                            
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

What i did now, is to add divs on the HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>                            
        <th><div style="width: 100px;">Codigo</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>                            
        <th><div style="width: 300px;">Description</div></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And the current Datatable configuration is:

```
tabla = $('#tabla').DataTable({
    language: {
        url: '/recursos/estilos/DataTables-1.10.1/js/locale/es_AR.json'
    },          
    "bSort": false
});
```

Comment: can you share your fixed code also .. so that other people can refer it.

Answer (score 2):

1. set autoWidth: false;
2. set px values to first 3 columns; 
   important:
   check if the table width is a bit more than 3 columns + final one;
3. adjust the table width and 4th column.

   ```
   $('#example').DataTable({ //four column table
       autoWidth: false, //step 1
       columnDefs: [
          { width: '300px', targets: 0 }, //step 2, column 1 out of 4
          { width: '300px', targets: 1 }, //step 2, column 2 out of 4
          { width: '300px', targets: 2 }  //step 2, column 3 out of 4
       ]
   });
   ```

> [Specifying a fixed column width in jQuery Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706537/specifying-a-fixed-column-width-in-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 1):

you can define a CSS class to your column like this :

> aoColumns : [
>         {  "sClass": "my_class" }]

And in your CSS :

```
.my_class 
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:200px;
}
```