# Jquery datatable - how to make table non-responsive

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable to show values in my application. The table contains many columns and the library is "scaling" them , reducing width and I am able to to see all columns on one page.

but in this case it looks bad, I'd like to create the table non-responsive and have a slider to see additional columns.

Was trying to find something in google but unsuccessfully.

`Responsive: false` doesn't work

Will be thankful for your support,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: remove **nowrap** class from table if there

Comment: There is no NOWRAP class in my table

Comment: do you want to display all column on single page without scrolling?

Comment: can you add some code that you tried ?

Comment: the code is very simple : $('#datatable').dataTable();

Comment: I want to see all columns in a row, but with "normal" width

Comment: then why don't you go for custom width as said over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25752866/5813861)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: false
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your problem well it should be something that can help You.

You need to enable scrollX like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable( {
  "scrollX": true
 });
});
```

docs & live example:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

You can also set width for each column like this in your table object:

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
   { "width": "35px", "targets": [0,43,44,45,46,41] },
   { "width": "280px", "targets": 1 }
  ]
 });
```