# How to fix column width in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new to web development. I have searched a lot but couldn't find the solution. I want to adjust all the 5 columns on the screen without any scroll. The grade column, as shown in the image, is going outside of the border. How can I fix the table on the screen? the problem is with the search bar above each column. Help will be appreciated

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php'); ?>


<head>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.8/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
<style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" >

 
    div.table {
        width: 90%;
    }
    

</style>
</head>

    <body>
        <?php  include('navbar_teacher.php'); ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <?php include('teacher_sidebar.php'); ?>
        
                <div class="span9" id="content">
                     <div class="row-fluid">
                        
                        <!-- block -->
                        <div id="block_bg" class="block">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                                <div class="muted pull-left">Exam List</div>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <div class="table">
                                    <table class="container1" id="example" >
                                    <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                                <th >Name of Student</th>
                                                <th>Exam Title</th>
                                                <th>Exam Description</th>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>Grade</th>
                                                
                                              </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                                <?php $class_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT 
                                                        quiz.quiz_title,
                                                        quiz.date_added,
                                                        student.firstname,
                                                        student.lastname,
                                                        student_class_quiz.grade,
                                                        quiz.quiz_description 
                                                    FROM quiz 
                                                        INNER JOIN class_quiz ON class_quiz.quiz_id = quiz.quiz_id
                                                        INNER JOIN student_class_quiz ON class_quiz.class_quiz_id = student_class_quiz.class_quiz_id 
                                                        INNER JOIN student ON student_class_quiz.student_id = student.student_id 
                                                    ORDER BY quiz.quiz_id") or die(mysqli_error());
                                        
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($class_query) > 0 ){
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($class_query)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
                                        echo "<tr>
                                        
                                        
                                        <td>" . $row['lastname'] .  $row['firstname'] . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $row['quiz_title'] . "</td>
                                        <td>" .   $row['quiz_description'] . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $row['date_added'] . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $row['grade'] . "</td>
                                        
                                        </tr>";
                                        }
                                }
                                        ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /block -->
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php include('script.php'); ?>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        

        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
 
        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
 
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: false,
        
     //   fixedHeader: false,
        retrieve: true,
         scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
      //  scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        columnDefs: [
            { width: '20%', targets: 0 }
        ],
       // fixedColumns: true
        
        //paging: false
        
    } );
} );
    
    </script>   

</html>
```

Comment: What for are you posting that whole thrash while you just asking about formating of one HTML element? Why do you tag it with tags [tag:javascript], [tag:php], [tag:jquery] while all you ask is one HTML element and required CSS? Please read about [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the PHP or the SQL. Remove those, and show us instead a sample of the table as it appears in the browser (e.g. as taken from your browser's View Source feature). And then show us all the relevant HTML and CSS, not just the table - it appears it's going outside a container, but we don't know anything about that container or its rules. Make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please, and remove anything that isn't directly relevant to that. Also, are you using Bootstrap? What version? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying a fixed column width in jQuery Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706537/specifying-a-fixed-column-width-in-jquery-datatables)

Comment: @adyson someone suggested the changes and i approved. i am new both here and to web development. I am a student so didnt know much. sorry for that. yes i am using bootstrap version is v2.3.2.

Comment: @bhautik sir this isn't working either. the width when give this specified value, enlarge the table but the column size doesn't reduce when i try to reduce the value to adjust

Comment: Someone made changes but not the ones I was suggesting. P.s. that is a very old version of bootstrap.